# Which clans are most likely to embrace/sire a librarian?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

My Vampire the Masquerade (5e) character was a librarian in their human life, before they were sired. I want to explore their backstory more but I couldn’t think of any reasons.

By lore, are their any clans especially likely to have reasoning to and as such favour siring mortals with such a career/background?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few who might be more inclined to sire a librarian, albeit this is under the assumption that the character is a *scholarly* librarian.

One invested in the sort of work they do and materials they deal with

For the clans who might be more interested in Siring such an individual there are the:

- You have the "**Banu Haqim**", who are the assamites that have since aligned themselves with the Camarilla. They have the "Vizier Caste", who are scholars -the particularly passionate and obsessed (obsessive being an emphasised trait) with their fields being more likely to be recruited here. It should be noted though: if this character of yours is of exclusively European-descent, the chances do decrease slightly as members of such background are uncommon in the clan (although not non-existent):

> The Assamites draw most of their childer from the Middle East, North
>   Africa, and surrounding areas, but this does not mean they are all
>   Arab. They also Embrace childer from the Indian subcontinent,
>   Persians, Turks, Malays, Central Asia groups such as the Uzbeks and
>   Kazaks, and various Mediterranean groups. Assamites from European or
>   far Eastern ethnic groups are not unheard of, but are uncommon.

The character would also likely be religious too, although "virtually any religious background" is described as acceptable.

- Then there's the "**Tremere**". They are admittedly very picky, but do draw from those who were scholars and/or occultists in life. So a librarian might be a candidate, particularly if they ever got their hands on any occult books or simply showed to be the sort of determined/"driven" (them liking that too) individual who would be able to take to such a book in the future.
- You also have a rare branch of the "**Brujah**" to otentially keep in mind, specifically the "**Idealists**:

> In contrast to Iconoclasts, Idealists are the intellectuals and
>   theorists of the clan. They are usually elders or ancillae

As said here, these are the sort interested in intellectual and scholarly pursuits and who, as such, may be interested in Siring a librarian as part of their goal to regain the footing that they lost.

- The "**Malkavians**" are also a potential, as they number a few scholars and scientists and the sort amongst them. If the librarian had any mental illnesses or peculiarities beforehand, the chances increase further for this potential scenario:

> The Malkavians are one of the more intellectually focused of the
>   Camarilla clans (with the Tremere arguably being the only clan as
>   interested in cerebral pursuits). As a result, Malkavian candidates
>   for the Embrace tend to be intelligent and more than a little... odd.

That's the sort of clans I'd say are more likely to embrace/sire a librarian than the others.

But, even bearing that in mind: being a librarian doesn't necessarily have to be *completely* linked to why they were sired. Perhaps just a factor.

For instance, here's some potential scenarios:

- Perhaps while working in the library, they noticed a regular visitor who would frequently be alone, staring off and muttering to themself. Feeling they looked like they could do with some company, the librarian started making an effort to chat with and keep them some company when they could, while they were there. Eventually, after long enough of this, the **Malkavian** decides to embrace their new friend.
- Filing and putting away books was a nightmare, it took forever due to members of the public just leaving it all over the place and now they are heading home alone in the dark. Unfortunately for them, they do not make it home - they are attacked by someone, who they desperately give their all in trying to get off them. And, as a result of that determination to live-

  > A **Gangrel** sire often chooses a prospective candidate for the Embrace during feeding. If the mortal prey resists, fighting against what is happening, then his reward after death may be a taste of Gangrel blood.
- Politics sucks and is immensely unfair. There's so many cases of injustice in the world and as a librarian, this character is fully aware and educated on these such injustices - past and present. They only wish they could do more about them. Something, which they wind up discussing with a group of some people who started coming into the library, riled up and wanting to learn more about revolutions and politics and way to make your stance - perhaps even discussing attending some protests with them and stick it to the oppressors and 1%. As a result of this, one or more of the group of **Brujah** come to the decision that this librarian would be a good addition to the fold.
- The librarian is quite a fan of plays and novels, the telling stories and the craftsmanship of it all - making a habit of trying to go to the theatre as well, to see life breathed into some of their favourite plays. As such, when one particular person comes to ask for recommendations, the librarian is always entirely prepared to give ones and discuss opinions. As a result, the **Toreador** takes a liking to them and their fellow appreciation on such arts and decides to give them the Embrace.

In these cases, them being a librarian played a role in putting them in contact with who would become their sire, they would not have met otherwise - but there were other factors at play too, if you want more leeway in potential Clan for them to belong too.

I hope this all helps!